# Google Apps script authorization prompt asks for more permissions than it should

Tags: google-apps-script

I am using Google Apps Script to enable a custom drop-down menu in Google Slides. When I am asked to authorize the script, it asks for permission to View my Google Spreadsheets, but I don't use the Spreadsheet service in my code (I tried searching for "Spreadsheet" in my code).

Spreadsheets is listed in the project scopes, but I can't seem to remove it directly from there. The manifest does not show anything Sheets related. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

[image]

Comment: For example, is this useful for your situation? https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/71448583

Comment: Yes, that is applicable. It seems there is a bug then...Thanks for the info.

Comment: I was able to get around this by calling out "explicit scopes" to override the default scope detection:  https://developers.google.com/apps-script/concepts/scopes#setting_explicit_scopes